# What is the significance of this excel vba code Sheet.Range.End().Row?

Tags: excel, vba

What does this code below mean?

```
For i = 2 To Sheet3.[a65536].End(3).Row
```

I don't understand the significance of

```
Sheet.Range.End().Row
```

Comment: That's a very poorly coded attempt to find the last row. [This is the proper way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-excel-with-vba).

Answer (score 2):

### End Parameters

- The `3` means `xlUp`, but I have never seen anyone use it.
- The 'proper' way, using `End` to get the row of the last occupied cell in column `A`, in your case, would be:

  ```
  For i = 2 To Sheet3.Cells(Sheet3.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
  ```

  where `xlUp` makes it more readable while using `Rows.Count` makes it more flexible (since `Excel 2007`, the rows count is `1048576`, `65536` was prior to it.) i.e. you can use the code in any version of `Excel`.
- In the following code the first two examples show how to get the last 'occupied' row where the first example is the preferred way, 'going' from the bottom cell up.
  The last two examples show how to get the last occupied column where the first example is the preferred way, 'going' from the right most cell to the left.

**The Code**

```
Sub explainEnd()
    
    Const FirstCol As String = "A"
    Const FirstRow As Long = 1
    
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = Range("A1:J21")
    rg.Value = 1
    
    Dim RowOrCol As Long
    
    RowOrCol = Cells(Rows.Count, FirstCol).End(xlUp).Row ' 3 or -4162
    Debug.Print RowOrCol ' 21
    
    RowOrCol = Cells(FirstRow, FirstCol).End(xlDown).Row ' 4 or-4121
    Debug.Print RowOrCol ' 21
    
    RowOrCol = Cells(FirstRow, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column ' 1 or - 4159
    Debug.Print RowOrCol ' 10
    
    RowOrCol = Cells(FirstRow, FirstCol).End(xlToRight).Column ' 2 or -4161
    Debug.Print RowOrCol ' 10
    
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you so much for such a detailed answer, much appreciated!

Comment: What a helpful support for an apparent beginner +:) Side note: maybe you could suggest use of `Option Explicit` and fully qualified range references, too.